# How to hide and show side bar with the same shortcut in Visual Studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I have the following shortcut for VS Code on MacOS:

```
  {
    "key": "cmd+1",
    "command": "workbench.scm.focus"
  },
```

That will focus the source control pane and show it if the side bar is not visible. What I want now is to to hide the side bar when I click `Cmd+1` again and the scm pane is open. Right now I can hide the side pane with `Cmd+B`:

[image]

Is there a way to change that? I have been trying to make a conditional shortcut but I have not found the way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
  {
    "key": "cmd+1",
    "command": "workbench.scm.focus",
    "when": "!workbench.scm.visible"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+1",
    "command": "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility",
    "when": "workbench.scm.visible"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your flow, but have you looked at the `when` clause contexts?

Find a list here: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#available-contexts

And you can then use those in the `When` column:

[image]